# Create Algolia custom index magento

Tags: magento2, algolia

I need to use the event  "algolia_product_index_before" and add an object "_geoloc":{ "lat":14.23890,"lng":25.234773} I have lat lng attributes added to every product. How do I go about building this observer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add your object to Algolia, in your event observer, you can do something like this:

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $customData = $observer->getData('custom_data');
    $customData->setData(
        '_geoloc',
        '{ "lat":14.23890,"lng":25.234773}'
    );
    return $this;
}
```

I hope this will help you to solve your issue

Cheers